# Typescript find an element (object) inside an array and then filter the same object's array property

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have and array of objects with a structure like:
[{id:"1",name:"shirt",price: 30, variants: [{id:"1", color:"blue",price:40,{id:"2",color"red", price: 50}]}]

Its basically an array of objects with each object containing an array of variants. I am trying to write a function (its basically a wishlist) that given a productId and variantId constructs a wishlist with the products containing only the variant I want. I have tried the below code with not much luck.

```
const wishlistItems = products.filter((item: Product) =>
      wishlist.items?.find(({ productId }) => item.id === productId)
    )

    wishlist.items?.forEach((item) => {
      const product =
        item &&
        wishlistItems.find((wishlistItem) => wishlistItem.id === item.productId)?.variants.filter(variant => variant.id === item.variantId)
      

      if (item && product) {
        item.product = product
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to attempt with this code ?

```
const product =
        item &&
        wishlistItems.find((wishlistItem) => wishlistItem.id === item.productId)?.variants.filter(variant => variant.id === item.variantId)
```

You must know that the `item &&` will be ignored, and `const product` will only contain the second part of the statement, which should be an array of all the variant having the good id. Moreover, you could reduce your statement like this :

```
const product = item?.variants.filter(variant => variant.id === item.variantId)
```

If your objective is to filter the variants array of your product in order to keep only the ones having the good id, you could do this :

```
wishlist.items?.forEach((item) => {
      item.variants = item?.variants.filter(variant => variant.id === item.variantId)         
    })
```

Comment: items is an array of objects containing productId, variantId (=wishlistItem). Products is an array of all products as objects containing product properties as well as all the variants of the product. What I want to do is construct a wishlist by filtering the products array by the productId of the wishlistItems but also filter the variants on each product by the variantId which I get from wishlist item. 

Product = {propertyA, propertyB, propertyC, etc, Variants:[{propertyA, propertyB, propertyC, etc,}]
wishlistItem = { productId, variantId}
Wishlist = { items: Product[] }

Comment: my objective is for each wishlistItem filter Products array and then filter the resulted product to display all properties but only the variant listed in wishlistItem

Comment: I think I didn't understand what you were asking, so you already have a wishlist, but you are trying to replace every product of this wishlist by a new wishlist ?

Comment: Anyway that is what you are currently doing, your function replaces some Product object by some other Product objects inside your wishlist, you don't add or remove objects

Comment: Yes I already have a wishlist containing productId and variantId. My current code is wrong because it only returns the variant of the product found from the filter function. What I want is for each and every item in the wishlist: 1) get the product using the productId, 2) from this (and every other) product keep only the variant asociated with the variantId from the wishlist.

Comment: If you use `wishlistItems?.forEach((item) => { item.variants = item?.variants.filter(variant => variant.id === item.variantId)})`, the `wishlistItems` will contain all the products with the good productId, as well as all the variants with the good variantId. If your `wishlist.items` is empty, you could then just replace it by `wishlistItems`, if not then merge the two arrays like this `wishlist.items.concat(wishlistItems)`

Comment: There is no item.variants.... wishlistItems is an array of objects with this structure:
[
0: {productId: "49jhg40aa04kf", variantId: "f63haje3f8f"},
1: {productId: "34fghh5gk6sn", variantId: "3g0h7b2ghs"},
2: {productId: 6alou68ahfn4", variantId: "2dj429skf697"}
].

Products is an array of this structure:
[
0: {productId: "49jhg40aa04kf", name: "test", price: 40, variants: [0:{variantId: "f63haje3f8f", color: red, price: 50} 1:{variantId: "f63haje3f8f", color: green, price: 30}},
1: ....,
2: ....}